# What does "return $this" mean?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, return

I'm trying to understand this code, and when I arrived at the final line, I didn't get it. :(

**Can I have your help in order to find out, what does `return $this` mean ?**

```
public function setOptions(array $options) {
    $methods = get_class_methods($this);
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
        if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
            $this->$method($value);
        }
    }

    //???? - return what ?
    return $this;
}
```

**Update:**
I've removed my comments for better clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [11072965][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072965/why-to-do-return-this-in-setter-methods

Comment: It means a lot buddy.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This way of coding is called [*fluent interface*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fluent_interface). `return $this` returns the current object, so you can write code like this:

```
$object
  ->function1()
  ->function2()
  ->function3()
  ;
```

instead of:

```
$object->function1();
$object->function2();
$object->function3();
```

Comment: In php, do the calls have to be on seperate lines like that? I've more frequently seen chained calls in a line like this: $object->chop()->putInBowl()->bakeForTen(); Is it not OK in PHP?

Comment: They do not need to be, but I find this way much more readable - including having the semicolon on a line of its own.

Comment: so can we do `return $this` at the end of all our methods for convenience ?

Comment: You need to consider the usage of you class - if you're likely to call multiple methods of it right after eachother, it would be convenient do use method chaining. A perfect example is Doctrine's `Doctrine_Query` class.

Comment: I see, and when we do create()->from()->where()->leftJoin()... each of those are, actually methods. Very nice. :)

Comment: @Ziggy You don't have to put each method on a different line but it is strongly recommend you do that. Making a single line is extremely difficult to debug. Putting a method per line will make your life easier because the debugging error will pin point which line, and therefore which method, is causing you trouble.

Answer (score 8):

This will return the instance this method is called on. This usually done for achieving [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) so you can call stuff like:

```
CoolClass::factory('hello')->setOptions(array('coolness' => 5))->sayHello();
```

Where both `setOptions` and `sayHello` would be called on the same object.

Answer (score 7):

`$this` means the current object, the one the method is currently being run on. By returning `$this` a reference to the object the method is working gets sent back to the calling function.

So anyone doing

```
 $foo2 = $foo->SetOptions($bar);
```

$foo2 now refers to $foo also.

Answer (score 5):

you just can create a function chain

```
class My_class
{

        public function method1($param)
        {
                /*
                 * logic here
                 */

                return $this;
        }

        public function method2($param)
        {
                /*
                 * logic here
                 */

                return $this;
        }

        public function method3($param)
        {
                /*
                 * logic here
                 */

                return $this;
        }

}
```

so you can use this

```
            My_class obj = new My_class();

            $return = obj->method1($param)->method2($param)->method3($param);
```

Answer (score 4):

$this would be the class that contains that function.

So if you were to call it like:

`$obj->setOptions($options)`

it's going to return $obj, which has been set with the new options.  Generally when something is set like this, you don't have to capture the return, because it's affecting the object itself, but it makes it so you can use it inline.

Comment: I like your note that you don't have to capture the return. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: "$this would be the class that..." - Not the class. It is the object instance.

Answer (score 1):

If the SetOptions method is part of a ProgramOptions class or something, $this would refer to the class containing the method, so you would be passing back an instance of ProgramOptions.

Answer (score 1):

Its a common OOP technique called [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It main purpose to help chain multiple method calls in languages, that do not support method cascading, like PHP. So

> return $this;

will return an updated instance(object) of that class so it can make another call in its scope. See example in PHP,

```
class Class_Name {
    private field1;
    private field2;
    private field3;

    public function setField1($value){

        $this->field1 = $value;

        return $this; 
    }

    public function setField2($value){

        $this->field2 = $value;

        return $this; 
    }

    public function setField3($value){

        $this->field3 = $value;

        return $this; 
    }
} 

$object = new Class_Name();
$object->setField1($value1)->setField2($value2)->setField3($value3);
```