# Why return $this in setter methods?

Tags: php, zend-framework, return, getter-setter

Examining Zend Framework, I found that all setter methods (of those I’ve examined) return the instance of the class it lives in. It doesn't only set a value but also returns `$this`. For example:

```
  /*   Zend_Controller_Router   */
public function setGlobalParam($name, $value) {
    $this->_globalParams[$name] = $value;
    return $this;
}

  /*    Zend_Controller_Request    */
public function setBaseUrl($baseUrl = null) {
    // ... some code here ...
    $this->_baseUrl = rtrim($baseUrl, '/');
    return $this;
}

  /*    Zend_Controller_Action    */
public function setFrontController(Zend_Controller_Front $front) {
    $this->_frontController = $front;
    return $this;
}
```

And so on. Every public setter returns `$this`. And it's not only for setters, there are also other action methods that return `$this`:

```
public function addConfig(Zend_Config $config, $section = null) {
    // ... some code here ...
    return $this;
}
```

Why is this needed? What does returning `$this` do? Does it have some special meaning?

Comment: Returning `$(this)` means you can chain methods, eg `$myClass->method_1($x)->method_2($y)`.

Comment: I noticed this in the past as well and never thought to ask the question. Thanks I now have the answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `return $this` allows the chaining of methods like:

```
$foo->bar('something')->baz()->myproperty
```

Answer (score 4):

It's so that method calls on an object can be "chained", like this.

```
$obj->setFoo('foo')->setBar('bar')->setBaz('baz')->setFarble('farble');
```