# How to create a function with methods in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-5.3, fluent-interface

I need to create a function of this type, I do not know how it is done and I would like to learn

the function adds to the database, and receives some parameters

```
  event($user)->balande(2.00)->points(300);
```

example https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

```
activity('default')
   ->performedOn($anEloquentModel)
   ->causedBy($user)
   ->withProperties(['customProperty' => 'customValue'])
   ->log('Look, I logged something');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why to do return $this in setter methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072965/why-to-do-return-this-in-setter-methods)

Comment: The formulation of the question is different but it leads to the same topic

Comment: Yes. It is the same answer. That’s what a duplicate means in SO. It Is not a bad thing on itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple : the first function returns an object instance, and subsequent method calls are applied to this instance (they all return `$this`, allowing you to chain other method calls afterwards). Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

```
<?php

class Thing{
  public function doThat(){
      // [do something interesting in this object]

      return $this;
  }

  public function doSomethingElse(){
      // [do something interesting in this object]

      return $this;
  }
}

function Something(){
    return new Thing();
}

Something()->doThat()->doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, tomorrow in the first hour I will put it into practice

Comment: Yw. Don't really know why I've been downvoted there, let me know if you need anything more about this. Please consider accepting the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Upvoted, this is correct. No idea why you've been downvoted.

Comment: I do not know why, the same thing I was asking, try but do not let me, need reputation 15 or something like that.

Comment: Can you recommend a book or series where I can document about these issues and that is something empirical

Comment: @AndresMahecha you won't need more than the wikipedia page above since fluent interface is just about syntax and not much more. what's interesting here is what you can perform through objects and OO programming. I've found this book http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=346958 to be interesting and filled with php examples but you can also learn a lot by browsing OOP docs written for other programming languages, such as Java or C++.