# php return $this in class method

Tags: php

While I understand that this question is answered, but somehow that doesn't fit, what I am looking for.

I have got examples of method chaining use of return $this.

The snippets I got is like below from Magento2 code and find it difficult what it returns and how it can be used.

```
class Uploader
{
/**
     * After save logic
     *
     * @param  array $result
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterSave($result) // modified protected to public to access it in the example;
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

so if I try say for example

```
$a = new uploader();
$result = 10;
echo $a->afterSave($result);
```

I expect it will return 10, but I am getting `Catchable fatal error: Object of class Uploader could not be converted to string`

Kindly help me understand this.

Comment: `$this` is `Uploader` class or specifically the instance, its not `$result`

Comment: you mean within the method `return $this` is returning the instance of uploader class. can you explain how this can be used in a practical scenario. The method takes `$result` as parameter, but returning the `instance of the class`

Comment: so you don't need to initialize the class with `new uploader();` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "return $this" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956999/what-does-return-this-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here we are talking about methods that aren't supposed to return anything. Here `afterSave()` has nothing to return, and the fact that you are expecting it to return `10` is a misconception of the model pattern. If you want it to return `10`, as you just saved it, it probably is a property of your `uploader` instance.

That being said, when you have nothing to return, you have basically two choices:

- return `null` (or no return as it will return `null`
- return something usefull, for the code that is calling, as the instance itself (`$this`)

In the first case you'll have to use it as:

```php
    <?php
    $a = new uploader();
    $result = 10;
    $a->set($result);
    $a->save();
    $a->afterSave()
    [...]
```

With method chaining, you could have something like:

```php
    <?php
    $a = new uploader();
    $result = 10;
    $a->set($result);
        ->save()
        ->afterSave();
```

And that's basically what it is used for.

Comment: It looks like a nice explanation. but still figuring out how I can make use of `doSomethingElse()` or can access the `$result` argument supplied in the `afterSave` method.

Comment: You already have access to `$result` as you are passing it, `afterSave` is what you can call a callback method, which happens after an record is saved. Method chaining is a choice of pattern, vs returning `null`. Again `afterSave` is not supposed to return anything you could use. In case of a model architecture of code you probably have already under the hood something like `beforeSave()->save()->afterSave()` which could be followed by somthing like `afterCommit()`.

Comment: okay fpietka - just one more little clarification - like say afterSave method is not using the parameter `($result)` so to say that `afterSave()` and `afterSave($result)` won't make any difference and if yes, how?

Comment: As you defined it, `$result` is mandatory. But indeed the method won't use it, so you can send it anything and it won't change the outcome. If you want `$result` to be optional, you have to set it a default value in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return result after calling multiple chain functions, you can do it like this

```
class Uploader
{
    private $result = 10;
/**
     * After save logic
     *
     * @param  array $result
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterSave($result) // modified protected to public to access it in the example;
    {
        $this->result = $result;
        return $this;
    }

    public function calculateResult() // modified protected to public to access it in the example;
    {
        return $result * 784;
    }
}

//Here's how you call it.
$a = new uploader();
$result = 10;
$calculatedResult = $a->afterSave($result)->calculateResult();
```

Comment: okay. so if I don't use `this->result = $result`. how `($result)` parameter can be used?. this part I am still not able to make out.

Comment: Some how you need to pass the $result to another function, and I think using the private property to set the value is the best way.

Comment: Hi Ikenna, I have picked up that example used in Magento2. so they must be using it some way, which I am trying to understand. where the `afterSave($result)` is used as `protected _afterSave($result){ return $this}`. Does that make sense.